# Unable to complete Flutter installation

Tags: flutter, installation

I have installed the Flutter plugin 3.7.1 to VS code along with Dart 3.7.1, and two other Android related plugins.

When I run the `Flutter Doctor` command, it shows 3 issues and one of them is - Android SDK not found.

[image]

So, I downloaded this zip file from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

[image]

and manually placed the `tools` folder here - `C:\src\android_sdk\tools`

The tools folder has these files:

[image]

Running the Flutter Doctor command still shows the same reminder. Also When I run `Create Android Emulator`, it shows the error - `Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for null.`

Did I download the correct Android SDK package.

I do not know how to code in Java and hence would like to stick with VS Code. How can I solve these issues and get started.

**Steps I have tried so far:**

1. Included the path `C:\src\android_sdk\tools` for the `Path` variable in `System Variables`.
2. Added the variable `ANDROID_HOME` in System Variables with the value `C:\src\android_sdk\tools`.
3. Executed these commands in the Windows command prompt, which said - path updated and any open editor should be restarted to take effect:

   `C:\src\flutter\bin>flutter config --android-sdk C:\src\android_sdk\tools`
   `C:\src\flutter\bin>flutter config --android-sdk "C:\src\android_sdk\tools"`
   `C:\src\flutter>flutter config --android-sdk C:\src\android_sdk\tools`
   `C:\src\flutter>flutter config --android-sdk "C:\src\android_sdk\tools"`
4. Downloaded the [platform tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html) and extracted the contents of the
   file to `C:\src\android_sdk\tools\platform-tools\`
5. Followed the step by *ipereto* [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19805), which is to run a command in powershell. It created platforms & platform-tool folders.
6. Restarted the system.

Running flutter doctor in VS code still shows the same error.

**UPDATE:**
Android Studio is a must for Flutter to work. I missed this point. After installing Android Studio, Flutter & Dart plugins are to be installed in it. 
Then VS Code flutter doctor command did not show those errors.

Comment: I have faced exactly same issue and solved it from below: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/install-flutter-on-windows-with-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Flutter doesn't know where to look for the SDK. Did you [update your path](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path) ?

Comment: I tried adding this to 'Path' of User variables - `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android_sdk\tools\bin`. No luck.

Comment: - Type "env" in the Windows search, click "Edit environment variables for your account" and then "Environment variables".
 - Copy the SDK path (C:\ ... \android_sdk\tools).
Under "System variables" :
 - Select the row named "Path", click Edit, New and paste the path.
- Create a new system variable named "ANDROID_HOME" and paste the path as the value.
 - You might need to reboot your computer but this should do it.

Comment: For the first step, you mean to add under user variables & the second step is for system variables. right?

Comment: I added ANDROID_HOME value as a system variable - 
& the new error is `ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android_sdk\tools\
      but Android SDK not found at this location.`

Comment: Try to extract everything from the SDK zip into your android_sdk folder and edit the paths to point to that folder.

Comment: I did that & also ran this command - `flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android_sdk"`. Did not work

Comment: Did you reboot the computer ? And just to be sure, do you replace <username> with your actual username ?

Comment: Yes to both. It still says android sdk not found at that location.

Comment: I just figured I didn't clarify that **both** variables are system variables, maybe that's it. If not, I don't know how else I can help, sorry. Maybe try with Android Studio ?

Comment: remove everything and install JDK first and set system variables.Then Install flutter and set VS code accordingly!